# How to Store Image in Database Using Laravel With Base URL

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, intervention

When I'm storing an image into a database, then it doesn't upload with base URL. How can resolve this type of problem in Laravel?

```
public function uploadimage(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $picture = date('His') . '-' . $filename;
        $file->move(public_path('img'), $picture);

        $employee_image = Image::create($request->all());
        $employee_image->image = $filename;
        $employee_image->save();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image Uploaded Successfully']);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Select image first.']);
}
```

Comment: You are saving file name in database need to append base url while showing image in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this ....**

```
 public function uploadimage(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    $employees = new Image($request->input()) ;

     if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image') ;
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $employees->image = '/public/images/'.$fileName ;
    }
    $employees->save() ;
   return response()->json(['message' => 'Image Uploaded Successfully']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The public_path() function does not intend to be use to serve browser friendly uri, so, you should use `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL` facade instead.

e.g.:

```
$employee_image->image = URL::asset('storage/employees/').$filename;
$employee_image->save();
```

[Source: Laravel.IO](https://laravel.io/forum/04-07-2014-public-path-vs-url)

Comment: @Dineshkr. Once you upload the image in your public storage append the `$filename` with `URL::asset('storage/employees/')` and then save it in your DB. It will save your Image with a full url like: `http://localhost:8000/public/storage/employess/emp1_example.png` Thats what this code does.